# How to remove part of string in an array on last occurrence

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this simple array below, for example:

```
[
  { team: { name: 'Newport County AFC' } },
  { team: { name: 'Southport FC' } },
  { team: { name: 'AFC Fylde' } },
  { team: { name: 'FC United' } }
]
```

I want to remove the `FC` and `AFC` substrings of the given team names only on the last part/occurrence of the string.

I can only come up with this code below, which you can also see [here](https://repl.it/repls/ScratchyBoldProcessors)

```
arr.forEach(function(key, index, array)
{
    let teamname = key.team.name.replace(/AFC|FC/g,'');
    array[index] = teamname;
});
```

However, there is a problem, why? because some team names start with `FC` or `AFC` thus they will be removed and also my approach leaves the strings with whitespaces, which is not the intended way I want.

My expected output is:

```
['Newport County', 'Southport', 'AFC Fylde', 'FC United']
```

So how do I achieve it? is there a way to improve the code or a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look for the end of the string as well.

```js
var array = [{ team: { name: 'Newport County AFC' } }, { team: { name: 'Southport FC' } }, { team: { name: 'AFC Fylde' } }, { team: { name: 'FC United' } }];

array.forEach(function(object) {
    object.team.name = object.team.name.replace(/\s*(AFC|FC)$/, '');
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array::map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [String::replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) detecting if the string you want to replace is at the end using `$`. Also, you can use [String::trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to removes whitespace from both ends of the resulting string.

```js
const input = [
    {team: {name: 'Newport County AFC'}},
    {team: {name: 'Southport FC'}},
    {team: {name: 'AFC Fylde'}},
    {team: {name: 'FC United'}}
];

let res = input.map(
    ({team: {name}}) => name.replace(/AFC$|FC$/, "").trim()
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is the answer that returns the expected output.  Accepted answer does not.

Comment: @stever Yeah, I can see that, however, maybe that fits his needs too. I think he was more interested on know how to remove `FC` and `AFC` from the end that about the expected output. Thanks for support!

Comment: Likewise!  Still if one includes an expected output, it's nice if the accepted answer matches it.  Thanks Shidersz!

Comment: stever actually it was returning the expected output but he edited afterwards... it doesn't matter though.

Comment: @skyline33 Actually, the first version of the accepted answer returns the same that the last version. However, there is no need to keep this discussion. Is all ok!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option using replace with a different regex

```js
   var teams = [
      {
        team: { name: 'Newport County AFC' }
      },
      {
        team: { name: 'Southport FC' }
      },
      {
        team: { name: 'AFC Fylde' }
      },
      {
        team: { name: 'FC United' }
      }
    ]
    var junk = (/\sA?FC/g)
    var newTeams = teams.map((t) => {
    return t.team.name.replace(junk, "")
    })
    console.log(newTeams)
```